# Unable to get data-value of div in HtmlForm Helper

Tags: html, jquery, mvcrazor

I have an Html Form in a Wizard Wrapper with 2 for loops to display the model.  Each time the "Next button" is clicked, I need to save the specific unit.

Here is a part of the form (it is huge so I didn't want to post more than is necessary):

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAssessmentUnitScores", "Management", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SaveUnitScores" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AttemptId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AssessorId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmployeeCompanyId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequirementId)

                for (var i = 0; i < Model.Units.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var block = Model.Units[i];
    
                <div class="kt-wizard-v2__content" id="CurrentUnit" data-value="@block.UnitId" data-ktwizard-type="step-content" @(i == 0 ? "data-ktwizard-state='current'" : "")>
```

I need the "data-value" from the "CurrentUnit" div.

I tried using the wizard atrributes, then I tried putting an id on the div and using "getAttribute", neither works:

```
            var form2 = $('#SaveUnitScores');
            wizard = new KTWizard('kt_wizard_v2', options);
            wizard.on('beforeNext', function (wizardObj) {
            let sec = form2.find('[data-ktwizard-state="current"]');
            let curPg = sec.attr("value");
            var curUnit = form2.find('#CurrentUnit');
            var unitId = curUnit.attr('data-value');
```

I do not receive any javascript errors but "unitId" and "curPage" are both empty strings.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Comment: I will try.  Thanks!